# Angular directive code changes scope, but template shows the same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a directive like the following:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/myDirective.html?v=' + window.buildNumber,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.itemClasses = attrs.itemClasses || '';
        }
    }
})
```

and it's template looks like:

```
<div class="my-directive">
    <div class="items" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="item {{ itemClasses }}">{{ item.title }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and that directive is called in different places (one call per template) like this:

```
<my-directive item-classes="col-md-6"></my-directive>
...
<my-directive item-classes="col-md-12"></my-directive>
```

And all templates render the same value of `itemClasses`. At the same time link function sets proper value (I checked this fact by call of `console.log()`).

And if I add `scope: true` attribute to the directive's code - then all works fine. So, it seems like having own inherited scope helps. Could you explain me such behaviour?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `scope: true` you create a child scope for your directive and at the same time you inherit also the properties from the parent (in this case I think your controller). So all your directive's instances will have their proper scope.

Using `scope: false` your directive actually has no scope, and it shares the scope with its parent.

So, coming back to your question, having `scope:false`, when you do this:

`scope.itemClasses = attrs.itemClasses || '';`

you are setting the `itemClasses` property to the scope of the parent. 
It means that when you see in the link function it seems to work fine, but in reality every time you are going to override the same scope variable of the controller.

So, in your case, the first time you associate a scope variable to the parent controller:

`scope.itemClasses= 'col-md-6';`

but the second time actually you override the same scope variable of the parent with the new value:

`scope.itemClasses= 'col-md-12';`

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Please, let me summarise to be sure that I got it right. All `link` functions are called before any template render. So, my code just override the same attribute in the scope. And when it comes to render the template I have just a last assigned value. Right?

Comment: So, is the `scope: true` approach is the right one? Or there's something better?

Comment: Briefly: with scope false you use the parent's scope. So you are always setting the same variable in the parent's scope. So you override always the same variable. For the right approach it depends on what you are going to do with this value. What you are going to do with itemClasses? You need to change them when some variable in the controller changes?

Comment: I just want to be able to pass some argument to a directive. That value will be rendered in the template. I mean, I have 3 HTML block with the same layout. The only difference between them is the class added to the element. So I decided to create a directive and call it with the arugment (that changing class).

Comment: And yes, I understand the idea that `scope: false` makes me use parent's scope. So, yes, it will always set the same variable. I thought that it works like: setVariable -> render; setVariable -> render (so there's no problem). And from your answer I got that it works like: setVariable -> setVariable; render->render. So, we render after all set procedures are done. Right? :)

Comment: Perfect ;) if you just need css classes to be applied,  you can use standard `class` attribute and it should work. They would be related to the self element. So try simply this: `<my-directive class="col-md-6"></my-directive>` and `<my-directive item-classes="col-md-12"></my-directive>`.  Let me know for every issue or query Cheers :)

Comment: I want to apply those classes to each "most parent" element inside ng-repeat loop. Like for `<div ng-repeat=""><target-el class="item"><h1>{{item.title}}</h1><span>...</span></target-el></div>` template. So, just apply some list of classes to that `<target-el/>` element.

Comment: if you want just to apply those classes to the single items inside the ng-repeat, just use `<my-directive class="col-md-6">` and your directives will have the classes you specify there. Did I understand fine what you want to?

Comment: That `class` attribute in a directive call will lead to adding of that attribute's value to the most parent element in the template. I want those classes to be added to some child nodes (div#mostParent > div#ngRepeat > div.item).

Comment: Can you please update your answer showing me the template of the directive and indicating me the child where you want to apply your class? I will write you the code to do that

Comment: Question now contains the most realistic template. Target node - is each node with `item` class (those the most inner). And actually adding `scope: true` helped to me. In the meantime if you have any other best practice solution I will be very grateful to see on it. :)

Comment: I use AngularJS 1.2.2

Answer (score 1):

By binding the `item-classes` directly from the attributes you are basically making a copy of the attribute's values.

The solution for this is: if you want to make `input-classes` an input binding you may use isolated scope like so:

```
{
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        itemClasses: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/myDirective.html?v=' + window.buildNumber,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        // scope.itemClasses = attrs.itemClasses || '';
    }
}
```

Or just in case you don't want to use isolated scope, you can user `attrs.$observe`:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('itemClasses ', function(val) {
        scope.itemClasses = val || '';
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. AFAIU, isolated scope doesn't allow me to access attributes of outer scope. So, it's not the option for me. Taking into consideration the answer of @quirimmo, I'm not sure about 2nd solution. I mean, seems like it also will be executed before any template renders. I.e., on template render step we'll have last assigned value.